# UIScrollView: handling of dynamic content?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I've a Storyboard with a UIScrollView which contains two UILabels, a UIImageView and a UITextView. The content of the UIImageView and UITextView is dynamic and so are their height.

Currently I'm doing this inside my `viewDidLoad` to adjust the size of the UITextView after the dynamic text is inserted:

```
CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;
frame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height;
self.textView.frame  = frame;
```

Is this the way to change its height?

My next problem is to set the content size for the UIScrollView, to activate the scrolling. Is there a smart way to get the height of all its content or do I have to calculate the height for each element and set the sum of this as the content size of the UIScrollView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you had no space in between your objects, you could make a for loop in your scrollView.subviews and add up all the heights to set as the contentSize.

As you probably don't have everything tight together, you're probably better by getting the bottom most object and adding up it's frame.origin.y and it's frame.size.height (maybe you want to have some extra space in here, but that's up to you) and that will give you your contentSize.height to keep everything in there.